# New tmux shells use old version of .bashrc

Tags: bash, centos, tmux

I am currently in a situation where new shells created within a tmux session are sourcing an older version of my .bashrc, setting environment variables that I have since deleted from the file. The only explanation I can think of is that tmux cached that version of the file somewhere and is using that version instead of the real one. A newly created login shell outside of tmux reflects the changes to my .bashrc file, and does not have these environment variables anymore. What is causing this?

I have tried searching for the environment variable in the output of `PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE> ' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xl 7>&2` to no avail, so I don't know where it's being set.

Comment: How are you starting your shells? as a login or non-login shell?  See `man bash` and search for `^INVOCATION` to read about which rc files it sources depending on whether it's an interactive/non-interactive shell or login/non-login shell. My guess is that you are using login shells, but you don't have a line to source ~/.bashrc from your ~/.bash_profile. Note also that any environment variables exported before tmux was started will be inherited by tmux and any child processes (incl. shells) that it starts. Deleting a var from .bashrc won't change the running tmux's existing environment.

Comment: That's not tmux "caching" anything.  That's just how the environment works, child processes inherit the environment of their parent process. Also: child processes can NOT, under any circumstances, change their parent's environment (but that doesn't prevent programming some kind of protocol to allow a child to request that a parent do something to change its own environment)